# Implementing __eq__ using numpy isclose

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, floating-point, precision

I fear this might be closed as being a soft question,
but perhaps there is an obvious idiomatic way.

I have a class that contains a lot of information stored in floating point numbers. 
I am thinking about implementing the `__eq__` method using not exact but numerical equivalence similar to `np.isclose`. At the moment I have three options:

1. `__eq__` means exact comparison. But there is a function similar to `np.isclose`
2. `__eq__` means exact comparison. But there is a function similar to `np.isclose`and `__eq__` prints a warning everytime it is called and refers to using the function.
3. `__eq__` means numerical comparison.

I can not think of any use case where someone would like to do exact floating point comparison with this class. Hence option three is my favourite. 
But I don't want to surprise the user.

Comment: Option 1 is really the only sane one. Option 3 breaks transitivity of equality, with exciting results for things like set and dictionary containment. Option 2 would produce warnings in unexpected places: there are situations where Python is implicitly invoking equality tests, again to do with containment tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to add a context manager to switch modes:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
class MyObject(object):
    _use_loose_equality = False
    @contextmanager
    @classmethod
    def loose_equality(cls, enabled=True):
        old_mode = cls._use_loose_equality
        cls._use_loose_equality = enabled
        try:
            yield
        finally:
            cls._use_loose_equality = old_mode

    def __eq__(self):
        if self._use_loose_equality:
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

Which you would use as:

```
x = MyObject(1.1)
y = MyObject(1.100001)
assert x != y
with MyObject.loose_equality():
    assert x == y
```

Of course, this is still as dangerous as 3, but at least you now have control of when to enable the dangerous behaviour